# Преобразовать значение переменной Python

Tags: python

Есть переменная

```
list = "some text - 1\ntext - 999\ntext3\n"
```

Значение в эту переменную попадает динамически.. но во всех случаях это текст на конце которого \n
Нужно из переменной list построить значение другой переменной newList

*( если понадобится также есть переменная quantity = 3 которая показывает количество \n в переменной list)*

```
newList =  
[{\"text\":\"some text - 1 #{checkpoint_1}\",\"callback_data\":1}],
[{\"text\":\"text - 999 #{checkpoint_2}\",\"callback_data\":2}],
[{\"text\":\"text3 #{checkpoint_3}\",\"callback_data\":3}]
```

Написал такой код

```
list = "some text - 1\ntext - 2\ntext3\n"
list1= list.split("\n")

z = 0
for i in list1:
    if i != "":
        z += 1
        print('[{\"text\":\"' + i +' #{checkpoint_' + str(z) + '}\",\"callback_data\":' + str(z) + '}], ')
```

НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК УДАЛИТЬ ПОСЛЕДНЮЮ ЗАПЯТУЮ (((

или вот так

```
list1= list.split("\n")
list_mas = []

z = 0
for i in list1:
    if i != "":
        z += 1
        list_mas.append('[{\"text\":\"' + i +' #{checkpoint_' + str(z) + '}\",\"callback_data\":' + str(z) + '}]')

print(list_mas)
```

На выходе не могу получить переменную

```
newList = '[{\"text\":\"some text - 1 #{checkpoint_1}\",\"callback_data\":1}], [{\"text\":\"text - 999 #{checkpoint_2}\",\"callback_data\":2}], [{\"text\":\"text3 #{checkpoint_3}\",\"callback_data\":3}]'
```

Comment: Есть сайт stackoverflow и есть люди, которые на него попадают динамически, и есть вопросы, которые необходимо дополнять своими попытками решения.

Comment: согласен)).. приятно когда свои попытки решения сопровождаются помощью экспертов

Comment: а зачем там вообще запятые? Убери сразу все.  К тому же ты новый список не создаешь, а просто выводишь данные на экран.

Comment: Мне нужно на выходе получить вот такую переменную newList =  
'[{\"text\":\"some text - 1 #{checkpoint_1}\",\"callback_data\":1}],
[{\"text\":\"text - 999 #{checkpoint_2}\",\"callback_data\":2}],
[{\"text\":\"text3 #{checkpoint_3}\",\"callback_data\":3}]'

Comment: `НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК УДАЛИТЬ ПОСЛЕДНЮЮ ЗАПЯТУЮ` - join?

Comment: что нужно получить - список или строку? Если строку, то можно тупо взять срез без последнего элемента. Если список, то там не будет проблемы с запятыми, но код неправильный.

Comment: Нужно получить строку... взять без последнего элемента! ТОЧНО!!!

Comment: Но есть еще одна проблема((( Когда я выводил результат цикла принтом он показывает все элементы а как записать эти все элементы в переменную чтобы к ней добавить -1 к строке)))

Answer (score 0):

Через одно место, но все же решение )))

```
list = "some text - 1\ntext - 2\ntext3\n"

list1= list.split("\n")
list_mas = []
z = 0

for i in list1:
    if i != "":
        z += 1
        list_mas.append(r'[{\"text\":\"' + i +' #{checkpoint_' + str(z) + '}\",\"callback_data\":' + str(z) + '}]')

a = str(list_mas)
b = a[1:-1]
button_list = b.replace('\\\\' , '\\')
print(button_list)
```